# How to amend and install Jenkins plugin from Github

Tags: github, jenkins

I have forked my own repo of a Jenkins plugin on Github (and made some changes), and I have downloaded it as .zip file. How can I install this onto Jenkins? I assume I need to convert the .zip contents into a .hpi, but not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this out by creating a Maven project in Eclipse then running the maven command "package" against the pom.xml, this is what produces the .hpi file.